# 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on create object

Tags: python, django

Trying to insert data into a python model with a foreign key using the create object and getting a 'User' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

models.py

from **future** import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from ..loginRegistration_app.models import User

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    error_list = []
    def post_in(self, postData, user_id):
        if len(postData['post']) < 1:
            context = {'status':0}
            return context
        else:
            curr_user = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
            # print curr_user.last_name
            self.create(secrets = postData['post'], users_id = curr_user['id'])

class Like(models.Model):
    like = models.BooleanField()
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_likes')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    upated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Secret(models.Model):
    secret = models.TextField(max_length = 1000)
    likes = models.ForeignKey(Like, related_name = 'all_likes')
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_secrets')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    upated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    objects = PostManager()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Secret
from django.contrib import messages

def index(request):
    if 'user_id' not in request.session:
        return redirect('main:home')
    # put query to display most recent secrets

    return render(request, 'dojo_secrets_app/index.html')

def post_it(request):
    post_this = Secret.objects.post_in(request.POST, request.session['user_id'])
    return redirect('secrets:home')
```

error:

```
TypeError at /secrets/post_it
'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

self.create(secrets = postData['post'], users_id = curr_user['id'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is an attribute of the user instance, not some `dict` key:

```
def post_in(self, postData, user_id):
    # ...
    curr_user = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
    self.create(..., users_id = curr_user.id)  # id is an attribute
```

But since `user_id` is an attribute of your view, why not use it?

```
    self.create(..., users_id = user_id)
```

BTW, your `ForeignKey` fields should really have singular names (`'like', 'user'`), plural names make no sense semantically...